# Is it possible to get the last row filled?

Tags: gspread

In `gspread`, is it possible to get the last row or cell number that is filled?

The API reference page doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gspread has "row_count", but I am not sure it returns all rows in a spreadsheet, or just the filled ones.  If that doesn't help, there is a slightly less direct, but completely functional way to do it:

1.)  let's assume your data is in column A, and it has been filled in consecutively row by row (i.e. no skipped rows)

2.)  in another free cell in your spreadsheet--let's assume cell B1--use the native Google Sheets function COUNTA, which will count the number of values in a dataset, and specify column A as the target, i.e. "=COUNTA(A:A)"

3.)  now just request the value of cell B1 with gspread's acell, i.e. "last_row_updated = myWorksheet.acell("B1").value"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code, taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42476314/3671939) to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40781295/3671939):

```py
def last_filled_row(worksheet):
    str_list = list(filter(None, worksheet.col_values(1)))
    return len(str_list)
```